# chart.js : set vertical Label Orientation

Tags: javascript, css, charts

i need to set vertical values on top of the chart bars ,

actually i can set horizontal values , but that's not the result that i  want.

im using this code to set values on top of bars :

```
  animation: {
                        duration: 1,
                        onComplete: function () {

                            if(byDetails){

                                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                    meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {

                                        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                                        dataset.data[index] =  parseFloat(dataset.data[index]).toFixed(2);
                                        var data = dataset.data[index];

                                        if (withPersent) {
                                            data = dataset.data[index] + "%";
                                        }


                                        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 5;
                                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - random);


                                    });
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

that give me this : [image]

as you see the values on top of bars are horizontal  , but i need to change the orientation like this :

[image]

PS: im using the chart like this :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(chartDiv);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {type: 'bar',........});
```

any one have an idea haw to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you found an answer to your question.
My code:

```js
animation: {
            duration: 1,
            onComplete: function () {

                if (byDetails) {

                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {

                            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                            dataset.data[index] = parseFloat(dataset.data[index]).toFixed(2);
                            var data = dataset.data[index];

                            if (withPersent) {
                                data = dataset.data[index] + "%";
                            }

                            ctx.save();
                            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 5;
                            ctx.translate(bar._model.x, bar._model.y - random);
                            ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);
                            ctx.fillText(data, 0, 0);
                            ctx.restore();
                        });
                    });
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't get the -1 comment.  Yes, if I run the code-snippet, there's a syntax error.  But right now, I've been googling/stackoverflowing how to write vertical text, and his idea with the transform and the rotate, and the save and restore ... I've seen nowhere.  This is a great post.  Thanks, Denis.